# Running mongodb docker container managed by supervisor

Tags: mongodb, docker, supervisord

In order to run multiple services inside **one** docker container (I know this is not how its intended) I chose an official docker image from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/tree/master/4.4)

and extended the `Dockerfile` by installing supervisor:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y supervisor && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 27017 9001 
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

And the `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongo]
user=root
command=/usr/bin/mongod --port 27017 --quiet --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --logappend
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
user=root
startsecs=3                   
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/mongod.log
```

I'm only posting the mongodb service for the sake of simplicity. With docker-compose I'm spinning up the mongodb docker-container managed by supervisor and another service that tries to connect to the database:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb:
    restart: on-failure:2
    image: mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    init: true
    networks:
      - mongonet
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    volumes:
      - ./datadir:/var/lib/mongo

#
  login-service:
    restart: on-failure:2
    container_name: login-service
    image: login-service
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - mongonet
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"


networks:
  mongonet:
    driver: bridge
```

This produces the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar!/:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

It seems like there is a network configuration i'm missing. I've tried changing bindIP in `/etc/mongod.conf.orig` but it seems like the mongodb service is not picking up this configuration after restart. The logs tell me that mongodb is waiting for a connection:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-17T10:07:37.020+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Is there some sort of parameter for the supervisor command im missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and i wasn't too far off with the network configuration in supervisor. By adding `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` to the supervisor command i was able to bind all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses as stated  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/). There is also a parameter `--bind_ip_all` which helped me accomplish the same goal. Se here is my final supervisor configuration:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongo]
command=/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip_all
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
```

**Alternative**:

Also if you don't need to build the image yourself there is an even better solution:

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:bionic

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y supervisor && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 27017 9001 

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

... and the supervisord.conf file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongo]
command=/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mongod
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
```